# Smart pointer toolkit using variadic CRTP

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, smart-pointers, c++20, crtp

I am about to design and implement a kind of smart pointer toolkit - a set of classes to define various types of smart pointers like unique_ptr, intrusive_ptr, shared_ptr, observing_ptr, tagged_ptr etc. Just to mention I am working in freestanding environment where I have no c++ library available. My intersion is to avoid code duplications, make it follow an elegant design principle. Let me describe my thoughts in there.

Design Considerations:
I wanna use variadic CRTP approach to mixin the desired pointer features, the traits. For every feature set there shall be once trait class like:

```
/* Functions to support move semantics like move constructor, move assignment operator */
template<typename DERIVED>
class MoveablePointer { ... };

/* Functions to manage pointee lifetime - using the deleter class */
/* EDIT: template<typename DERIVED, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<typename DERIVED::element_type>> */
template<typename DERIVED, typename DELETER> /* <-------- Default removed here as EDIT */
class Owning { 
public:
    using deleter_type = DELETER;
    
    /* ... */
};

/* Functions to use least significant bits effectively unused due to alignment to hold additional payload information */
template<typename DERIVED, typename TAGS, size_t ALIGNMENT>
class Tagged { ... };
```

and then to mixin the traits into one smart pointer class using variadic CRTP pattern:

```
template<template<typename> class... TRAITS>
struct make_traits {
    template<typename DERIVED>
    struct Traits : public TRAITS<DERIVED>... {};
};
template<typename T, template<typename> class POINTER_TRAITS>
class SmartPointer : public POINTER_TRAITS<SmartPointer<T, POINTER_TRAITS>> {
public:
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;

    /* ... */
};

template<typename T, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>>
using unique_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<MoveablePointer, Owning>>;

template<typename T>
using observer_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<Observing, NonOwning, Copyable, Moveable>>;

/* ... and to continue defining type aliases to cover various smart pointer variations... */
```

Basically this idea seem to work once the particular traits have the same set of template arguments (just `template<typename DERIVED>`). But as sampled above, it is not the case as for instance the `Tagged` trait or `Owning` trait require more template parameters like `ALIGNMENT` or `DELETER` respectively.

So my question is - how to change the implementation of make_traits<> and SmartPointer<> class templates to support variadic trait's template arguments?

Many thanks to anyone willing to help me! Martin

**EDIT**: Code adjusted as the discussion flows below the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use variadic template:

```
template<template<typename, typename...> class... TRAITS>
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct make_traits {
    template<typename DERIVED>
    struct Traits : public TRAITS<DERIVED>... {};
};
template<typename T, template<typename> class POINTER_TRAITS>
class SmartPointer : public POINTER_TRAITS<SmartPointer<T, POINTER_TRAITS>> {
public:
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;

    /* ... */
};

template<typename T, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>>
using unique_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<MoveablePointer, Owning>::template Traits>;

template<typename T>
using observer_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<Observing, NonOwning, Copyable, MoveablePointer>::template Traits>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9688cd896603f432)

Comment: Once I try to instantiate the `unique_ptr` from the code above, it fails as expecting two template arguments in `make_traits::Traits`. I think the reason is missing 'forwarding' of `DELETER` to `Owning` in `unique_ptr` type alias... If so, how to do it?

Comment: @MartinKopecký: Issue with CRTP, is that `Derived` is incomplete type inside the CRTP. you have to create  external traits instead of using `Derived::type`: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edd09c8cb9331dfb)

Comment: Great, this solves the issue with the default type of `DELETER` in the `Owning` class definition. Is that the only way to define the `DELETER` (using default) or the type can be somehow defined in `unique_ptr` type alias? - to have the `DELETER`, let say without the default anywhere / to have it defaulted only in `using unique_ptr = ...` I have edited my original code to reflect that

Comment: I suggest to ask another question for this specific issue. (I think sentinel type might do the job.)

Comment: Thank you Jarod42 for your help. I have created the follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65375096/5677080