# Variadic CRTP Base Class with Additional Template Parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, crtp

I have a trait classes which are about to be used in variadic CRTP to extend the features of SmartPointer class.

This question is created as the followup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373058/5677080

An example trait class:

```
template<typename DERIVED, typename DELETER>
class Owning { 
public:
    using deleter_type = DELETER;
    
    /* ... */
};
```

Here comes the implemnetation of my SmartPointer which is being extended by variadic CRTP by those trait classes:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class POINTER_TRAITS>
class SmartPointer;

template<typename T, template<typename> class POINTER_TRAITS>
struct element_type<SmartPointer<T, POINTER_TRAITS>>
{
    using type = T;
};


template<template<typename, typename...> class... TRAITS>
struct make_traits
{
    template<typename DERIVED>
    struct Traits : public TRAITS<DERIVED>... {};
};
template<typename T, template<typename> class POINTER_TRAITS>
class SmartPointer : public POINTER_TRAITS<SmartPointer<T, POINTER_TRAITS>> {
public:
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;

    /* ... */
};
```

Finally there comes the type alias to define particular smart pointer type (here `unique_ptr`)

```
template<typename T, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>>
using unique_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<MoveablePointer, Owning>::template Traits>;
```

The problem is how to hand over the `DELETER` template parameter to the Owning class in `unique_ptr` type alias...

I guess something like (non-working code, just to demonstrate the intension):

```
template<typename T, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>>
using unique_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<MoveablePointer, Owning<DELETER>>::template Traits>;
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename DELETER>
struct MakeOwningWithDeleter {
  template <typename T>
  using type = Owning<T, DELETER>
};
```

Now you can pass `MakeOwningWithDeleter<DELETER>::type` to `make_traits`. Same trick you already use for `make_traits`.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct Partial{
   template<class...Us>
   using Apply=Z<Ts...,Us...>;
};
```

then

```
 template<typename T, typename DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>>
 using unique_ptr = SmartPointer<T, make_traits<MoveablePointer, Partial<Owning,DELETER>::template Apply>::template Traits>;
```

This does require this change:

```
template<typename DELETER, typename DERIVED>
class Owning {
```

Comment: Or change order in `Partial` to fix last parameters instead on first (logical) ones.

Comment: @jarod surs, but I'd rather a metafunction be simple and famous.  Partial apply from past argument is a bit more obscure.